# how to select all data from mysql table where column is an array or single and my value match with one item of this array?

Tags: php, mysql

Please could someone help me? I want to select all values in mysql table where the column that i want to check get a value is mix with aingle or array of values....... So to be more clear I have  a table to store all messages from many sender to one or many reciever....

my functions is

```
public static function find_messagesTo_by_user_id($mess_to=0) {
          global $database;
          $mess_to = $database->escape_value($mess_to);
          $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name;
          $sql .= " WHERE mess_to = '{$mess_to}'";
          $sql .= " AND mess_deleted = 0";
          $sql .= " ORDER BY mess_created_date DESC";
          $result_array = parent::find_by_sql($sql);
          return $resultrray;
      }
```

So 'mess_to ' has array and single value .... they are only numbers Like (1, 15, 25 ,26 ,27 , array(1,25, 27) , 31, 42, .......)

Please, i break my head on it :)

I waiting for any help?

Comment: That's crazy!  Can you give a print_r($mess_to);

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Maluchi's answer. Make sure your data looks like:

```
| mess_to         |
+-----------------+
| ,123,           |
| ,123,456,152,1, |
| ,456,567,       |
| ,3,             |
```

So surround each value in `,`. then you can safely do:

```
WHERE `mess_to` LIKE "%,{$mess_to},%"
```

This ensures that `$mess_to = 1` will match only the 2nd row, and not the 1st as well.

---

You could also denormalize your data and make a table to `JOIN` on.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading it correctly, $mess_to is passed into the function and could contain either a single value or it could be passed in an array.

When matching multiple values, the SQL should be looking for a comma-separated list. The where clause needs to be IN the list rather than EQUAL to the list.

Try:

```
public static function find_messagesTo_by_user_id($mess_to=0) {
      global $database;
      $mess_to = $database->escape_value($mess_to);
      $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name;
      $sql .= " WHERE mess_to IN (" . implode(',', $mess_to) . ")";
      $sql .= " AND mess_deleted = 0";
      $sql .= " ORDER BY mess_created_date DESC";
      $result_array = parent::find_by_sql($sql);
      return $resultrray;
  }
```

See this line in particular:

```
$sql .= " WHERE mess_to IN (" . implode(',', $mess_to) . ")";
```

**Code edited with geomagas's comments! (Thank you geomagas!)**

Comment: Good thinking! Two things though: 1) `IN` needs parentheses, not quotes and 2) you should `implode()` [recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899971/implode-and-explode-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Oh, and a third: `implode(',',array($mess_to))` would cover the single-value case (provided the above recursiveness).

Comment: Please see previous comment.

Comment: Not sure if my edits cover point 2. I also don't read the problem as passing in an array with arrays included. Maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Well, no it doesn't. Please see the examples in [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xuj-k24).

Answer (score 0):

asuming your column is like this

```
| mess_to |
+---------+
| 1       |
| 1,2,3,4 |
| 2       |
| 3       |
```

you can use the [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator:

```
$sql .= " WHERE mess_to LIKE '%{$mess_to}%'";
```

this will match every row where `mess_to` has the string value of `$mess_to` (your column data type should be string for this to work).

Comment: But what if you have `11,12,13` will that match `$mess_to = 1`? (or `2` or `3`)